# Input from multiple lines in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

Hello the problem I am trying to solve says : "There are at most 10000 test cases in the input in separate lines" so how can I write a code that gets input from those lines, I don't know how many lines there will be?

Comment: Keep reading them until there are no more.

Comment: how do I do that I am really new to C language. I am trying to do that,googling and I am really emotionally tired + I have an exam soon lol

Comment: you can use a text file as input, or create multiline input directly on the shell (how exactly depends on the OS and the shell you are using).

Answer (score 1):

Read *carefully* some [documentation on C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) programming language.

You could be interested in [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline), perhaps mixed with [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and of course looping on them.

Define on paper what an input line is. The [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation might help.

Of course read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques.

Study for inspiration the source code of some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) program on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) related to your interests.

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  then use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Good luck for your exams. Their purpose is to *teach you things*; of course you need to *experiment* some code of yours.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to use fgets but I don't really understand it much. It gives me the result right after I input and press enter and then asks me for another input but I want several lines of input and THEN result